# Proving that a continuous function is bounded below if a sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading this Lecture about gradient systems [(1)](https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/%7Eczaja/ISEM/13internetseminar200910.pdf), but in Lema 1.6 (p11-p12) the author states that: let $I=(a,\infty)$ if a function $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is a strictly decreasing continuos function in $I$, and exists a sequence $t_n\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty$ such that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)=p$$ then f is bounded below. I never saw this result i dont know how to prove it.

Note: i deffine $f:=\delta\circ u$

Comment: It follows from "strictly decreasing" and $t_n\to\infty$. So all of the interval is covered, and no oscillation is possible.

Comment: Please post your question in the question field.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to this forum, how i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is nonincreasing on $I$, we have

$$\inf \{f(x) : a < x <b\} = \lim_{x \nearrow\ b} f(x)$$

for all $b > a$. Since $f$ is continuous on $I$, this implies

$$\inf \{f(x) : a < x < b\} = f(b)$$
for all $b > a$. Now, $t_n \to \infty$, so $(a, \infty) = \bigcup_{n =1}^{\infty} (a, t_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (a, t_n)$, and therefore

\begin{align}
\inf \{ f(x) : a < x\} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf \{f(x) :a < x <t_n\} \\ 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} f(t_n) \\
&= p,
\end{align}

which implies that $f$ is bounded from below.

The limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a, t_n)$ is used here colloquially as the union of the increasing sequence $(a, t_n)$, which can be made precise in a number of ways that I think are irrelevant to the problem at hand.